# Why doesn't my Visual Studio 2015 RC compile properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC after using Code::Blocks for a long time.

To test it I just created a simple Hello World program, but it won't compile properly.

This is the output from the compiler:

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Build started: Project: Sandbox, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.
1>
1>  cl  ■/
1>
1>CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type ' ■/', object file assumed
1>  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.22816.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>  /out:.exe
1>  ÿþ/
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'ÿþ/.obj'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Try using ASCII characters only in the filename and adding .cpp

Comment: Your build is actually calling the Visual C++ 6.0 compiler (MSC version 12.00.xxxx). Ah, the memories...

Comment: I understand that from some stuff I read on the internet, but how do I fix this?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you created a brand new solution and project (File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 Console Application), left all settings on default, wrote a hello world program from scratch, and got this when building?

Comment: Not exactly, I first created an empty project instead of a Win32 Console Application, then I left all settings on default and wrote a Hello World program to test Visual Studio, and then I indeed got this error when building.

Comment: In the project properties, look at `VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories`. Is the path to the old toolset in there?